# Text halfway a line using coordinates in an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, technical-drawing, coordinates

I want to denote text halfway a line in an axis environment. Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{filecontents*}{batch_output_5.txt}
    NDOF Nelx Nely hnx hny condKBC errabsu errreleu errrelau beta beta_h
    640     9     9 1.111111111111111e-01 1.111111111111111e-01 1.234567890000000e+00 3.360958503340160e-03 6.801367190507313e-04 6.801883693667268e-04 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
    2864    19    19 5.263157894736842e-02 5.263157894736842e-02 1.234567890000000e+00 3.290048281511312e-04 6.939215705384151e-05 6.939186823409962e-05 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
    6089    29    29 3.448275862068965e-02 3.448275862068965e-02 1.234567890000000e+00 1.950755726148022e-04 4.494377155875972e-05 4.494363189976460e-05 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
    10450    39    39 2.564102564102564e-02 2.564102564102564e-02 1.234567890000000e+00 1.818287989540975e-04 3.111970271342298e-05 3.111966516370642e-05 1.234567890000000e+00 1.234567890000000e+00
   \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}
        [
            unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
            %unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            ymin=10^-5,
            ymax=10^-2,
        ]
            \addplot table[x index=3,y index=7] {\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt};

            % Triangle coordinates.         
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]3}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordAx{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]7}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordAy{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{[index]3}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordBx{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{[index]7}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordBy{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]3}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordCx{\pgfplotsretval}
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{[index]7}\of{\currfiledir batch_output_5.txt}
            \edef\triangleAcoordCy{\pgfplotsretval} 

            \coordinate (offset) at (0.2,-0.2);
            \coordinate (triangleAcoordA) at (axis cs:\triangleAcoordAx,\triangleAcoordAy);
            \coordinate (triangleAcoordB) at (axis cs:\triangleAcoordBx,\triangleAcoordBy);
            \coordinate (triangleAcoordC) at (axis cs:\triangleAcoordCx,\triangleAcoordCy);

            \coordinate (shiftedTriangleAcoordA) at ($(triangleAcoordA)+(offset)$);
            \coordinate (shiftedTriangleAcoordB) at ($(triangleAcoordB)+(offset)$);
            \coordinate (shiftedTriangleAcoordC) at ($(triangleAcoordC)+(offset)$);

            % Draw triangle.            
            \draw[black]    (shiftedTriangleAcoordA)--
                            (shiftedTriangleAcoordB)--
                            (shiftedTriangleAcoordC)--
                            cycle;
            \draw ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)+(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)-(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)$) node[anchor=north]{1};
            \draw ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)+(shiftedTriangleAcoordA)-(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)$) node[anchor=west]{2};
        \end{loglogaxis}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So the last two `\draw` commands should be something like

```
\draw ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)+((shiftedTriangleAcoordC)-(shiftedTriangleAcoordB))/2$) node[anchor=north]{1};
```

, but that command is not accepted. How do I solve this?

A secondary questions:

1) Is there a more elegant way to save the data from the table in LaTeX variables a use them in coordinates later on? It all looks so cumbersome.

2) The `0.2,-0.2` as used in the coordinate `offset`, where does it refer to? I don't think it's to `axis cs` or to percentages of the width and height of the graph?

Comment: Your example code works as expected in my system (TeX Live2014) and here's the resulting document: http://i.imgur.com/NFIcDvL.png Do you get anything different?

Comment: use `\draw ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)+.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)-.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)$) node[anchor=north]{1};`to get your text halfway the line

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes the given MWE work, but as I describe, I want the text to be halfway the lines, not at the ends. The `\draw` commands with which I try to do so give an error, see the second code environment.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Works like a charm.

Comment: @Adriaan and others: I'm working on a comprehensive answer. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler Sounds good. I hope there is a more elegant and less cumbersome way to get the same result. I'm thinking a macro for drawing a triangle with text at the middle of its edges would be nice. So, given three coordinates and three strings, plot a triangle with the strings at the middle of the edges.

Comment: @Adriaan Ah, sorry, I missed that. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Adriaan You can simply use             `\draw[black]    (shiftedTriangleAcoordA)-- 
                            (shiftedTriangleAcoordB)-- node[anchor=north] {1}
                            (shiftedTriangleAcoordC)--node[anchor=west] {2}
                            cycle;` and draw the triangle with the text in just one command.

Answer (score 2):

**Work-in-progress solution**

There are many ways, really. You could do

```
\draw ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)!0.5!(shiftedTriangleAcoordA)$) node[anchor=west]{2};
```

to get "halfway along the path from `shiftedTriangleAcoordC` to `shiftedTriangleAcoordA`", or use nodes directly in the path drawing (less repetition), like:

```
% Draw triangle.            
\draw[black] (shiftedTriangleAcoordA)-- node[left,pos=0.5] {halfway}
             (shiftedTriangleAcoordB)--
             (shiftedTriangleAcoordC)-- node[right,pos=0.5] {halfway also}
             cycle;
```

Or use the solution from the comments.

**Entering under-construction zone**

But you also asked about a better way to define the coordinates in the first place. The `pos=<fraction>` syntax can be used in `\addplot` commands as well.

*To be continued...*

Answer (score 1):

To get the text halfway the lines, use the commands

```
\coordinate (midBC) at ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)+0.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)-0.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordB)$);
\coordinate (midAC) at ($(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)+0.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordA)-0.5*(shiftedTriangleAcoordC)$);

\draw (midBC) node[anchor=north]{1};
\draw (midAC) node[anchor=west]{2};
```

Thanks to MaartenDhondt.